# Weird glitch in UITableView section header when reloading section above

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Have a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Lsgx7hpkeM).

I get this glitch when running this code:

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"following == YES"];
[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequ­est setPredicate:predicate];
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:THE_SECTION_WITH_THE_B­LOGS] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation­Automatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Why does the section header below the section I reload change it frame like this? Any solutions?

EDIT:

This is my viewForHeaderInSection:

```
(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (tableView != self.tableView)
return nil;
BLMenuTableSectionHeaderView *view = nil;

if (section != BLMenuSectionUser) {
    view = [[BLMenuTableSectionHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    if (section == BLMenuSectionFollowing){
        if ([self blogCount] > 0){
            [view setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Following", nil)];
            [view addSubview:self.editButton];
        }else{
            self.tableView.editing = NO;
        }
    }
    if (section == BLMenuSectionPosts){
        [view setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Browse", nil)];
    }
    else if (section == BLMenuSectionSettings)
        [view setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", nil)];
}

return view;
}
```

Comment: How does your tableView: headerViewForSection: implementation looks like?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm seeing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you shouldn't use `-beginUpdates` and `-endUpdates` in conjuction with a *reload*, but rather [when inserting or deleting](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1).

Not sure if this is causing your problems, but it might be worth checking out.

Is it the same regardless of animation type?

From [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and
>   selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and
>   indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously. This group of
>   methods must conclude with an invocation of endUpdates. These method
>   pairs can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and
>   selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count
>   might become invalid. **You should not call reloadData within the group;
>   if you call this method within the group, you will need to perform any
>   animations yourself**.